# subquery in group_concat with IN clause

Tags: mysql

`tbl_a`

```
id  dept_id
1   1,2,3
2   2,3
3   1
```

`tbl_b`

```
dept_id  dept
1        a
2        b
3        c
```

My query:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dept)  FROM tbl_b
WHERE tbl_b.dept_id IN (tbl_a.dept_id)) as departments
FROM tbl_a
```

This only returns the first value of the `tbl_a.dept_id`. 
I want to have a result as.

```
id      departments
1       a,b,c
2       b,c
3       a
```

Comment: NORMALIZE your table (tbl_a).

Comment: Your database design fails for First Normal Form. A column should not have multivalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if its possible to change the structure then [**normalize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it,use junction table which stores id of table a and  ids from table b  with a one-to-many relation,if you can't change schema you can use `find_in_set`

```
select a.id,group_concat(b.`dept` order by b.`dept`) departments
from a 
join b on(find_in_set(b.dept_id,a.dept_id) > 0)
group by a.id
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b00a5/3)